# Assert statement is never executed in async test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, c#-5.0, xunit.net

I am trying to learn [async-await programming model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) and [testing of async method using XUnit.net 1.9.2](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2012/01/xunit19.html). I wrote a simple WCF service CalculatorService which implements basic mathematical operation. I have used async-await model to implement these operation. Add function looks as follows:

```
public async Task<double> AddAsync(double n1, double n2)
    {
        // Mimicking time consuming work
        await Task.Delay(Delay);
        return (n1 + n2);
    }
```

I wrote a test case for AddAsync function. Test case looks as follows:

```
    [Fact]
    public async void ShouldAddAsync()
    {
        var calculatorSerivce = new CalculatorService();

        var result = calculatorSerivce.AddAsync(1, 1);
        // Mimicking independent work.
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        var actual = await result;

        const double expected = 3;
        Assert.Equal(expected,Convert.ToDouble(actual));
    }
```

I want debug the test case so I will understand the flow of control in *async programming model*. I put three breakpoints, one at

```
await Task.Delay(Delay);
```

, second at

`Thread.Sleep(10000);`

and third at

```
Assert.Equal(expected,Convert.ToDouble(actual));
```

Debugger hit first two points as expected but never hit third break point. Unusual thing is, test is passing even though I have made sure the failure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `async void` test method to an `async Task` method. As I describe in an MSDN article, [avoid `async void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).